# Сохранение состояния Page между переходами

Tags: wpf, .net, c#

Есть приложение, использующее WPF и его страничную систему навигации (страницы - экземпляры `System.Windows.Controls.Page`). Переход между страницами осуществляется с помощью `<Hyperlink>` и стандартной навигации (вперёд/назад).

Возникает вопрос, как сохранять состояние между страницами, т.к. по умолчанию страница пересоздаётся. Свойство `Page.KeepAlive` в данном случае не помогает, т.к. предназначено только для присутствия/отсутствия записи о странице в истории переходов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Сохранение состояния содержимого с помощью журнала переходов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms750478.aspx#RetainingContentStateWithNavigationHistory).

> Журнал обеспечивает запоминание данных в объекте Page при переходах, включая данные элементов управления. В частности, запись журнала для каждого объекта Page действует как временный контейнер для соответствующего состояния Page.
>
> ...
>
> Когда Page содержит элементы управления, не упомянутые в предыдущем списке, или когда состояние сохраняется в пользовательских объектах, необходимо написать код для сохранения в журнале состояния страницы при переходах Page.

То есть состояние стандартных контролов сохраняется в журнале, а для тех данных, которые не сохраняются, надо писать код на основе FrameworkPropertyMetadata.Journal или IProvideCustomContentState. Пример такого кода: [Custom Journal in WPF](http://vivekdalvi.wordpress.com/2006/09/14/custom-journal-in-wpf/). Логика переходов: [WPF Navigation](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется при такой задаче будет разумным вариант вынести содержание из класса страницы в отдельный класс, который будет глобальным на уровне приложения, и все контролы страницы связать с ним через Биндинг. Разместить объект можно как в ресурсах, так и управлять контекстом страницы программно. Контролы будут пересоздаваться, но содержательное состояние будет неизменным.